# How do I control what objects to encode using NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array filled with two different types of custom classes. Lets call them ClassA and ClassB.

I want to enabled encoding/serialization for ClassA, but not for ClassB.

I am using [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile] to serialize the list to disk.

I want NSKeyedArchiver to ignore all objects of type ClassB.

I dont want to iterate though the list and remove all ClassB objects, as I want to keep the original list in memory.

Comment: Instead of removing, why not create and populate a new array, then serialise that ?

Comment: "I dont want to iterate though the list and remove all ClassB objects, as I want to keep the original list in memory." Illogical. You can do both.

Comment: That would probably work if i manage copying the data over as this list acctually is contained inside another object that is serialized as well. But even through it works, I would like to know if there is a way to acctually control the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either subclass `NSArray` and override the `-encodeWithCoder:` method or copy and filter the original and then archive the copy rather than the original.

Comment: Subclassing the array is acctually a good idea. Copying the array with all its objects and subobjects and filtering it would involve a lot of code to conform to the NSCopy protocol.